# How to allow only one User to see "UpdateView"?

Tags: python, django, django-views, models

I have a `Users` and `Jobs`. If some `User` creates a `Job`, then and only then he/she can edit some information of this `Job`.

So he visits the url `.../job/update/<id>`. If the `Job` is created by him (the `User` is a `ForeignKey` in `Job`, then he can modify data. Otherwise he gets `404` error.

In `view` function, I would probably get current `User`s `id` and compare this `id` to `Jobs` `ForeignKey`.

But there are many patterns and shortcuts in `class views` so I'm curious how to do that this way.

```
class EditOrderView(UpdateView):
    model = Job
    fields = ['language_from','language_to','level','short_description','notes',
              'text_to_translate','file']
    template_name = 'auth/jobs/update-order.html'


class Job(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='orders', help_text=u"Zákazník")
    translator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='jobs', null=True, blank=True, help_text=u"Prekladateľ")
    price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, help_text=u"Cena")

    language_from = models.ForeignKey(Language, related_name='jobs_from', null=True)
    language_to = models.ForeignKey(Language, related_name='jobs_to', null=True)
    ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you can override [`.get_object()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object) method and include your own logic:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class EditOrderView(UpdateView):
    model = Job
    ...

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return get_object_or_404(self.model, pk=self.kwargs["pk"], customer=self.request.user)
```